# HTML navigation bar with unordered list vs other methods

Tags: html, css, nav

From **[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp)**, it shows and explains how to make a *navigation bar* using *unordered lists*. I personally do not use this method, but have used pictures to support each button of my navigation list. I know lots of other people use many different ways.

Which method is the best and easiest?

- *Unordered list* method for links
- *Using pictures*
  for links
- Making *plain anchor elements* for links
- etc...

From a YouTube video that could be outdated, it said that *Internet Explorer* did not update to HTML5, therefore it was best to use *Unordered Lists* because it could not read the nav element.

I personally have tried some of these ways, and the best for me if I am making custom, more entertaining buttons, will use the picture method. To me the unordered list method is more  complicated and looks more classic.

Which of these ways would be the *easiest*, most *efficiency* way, with giving the best *results*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I've used all three at the same time!

Depends on you're goal, when I use ul it is usually to make a type of drop down menu pure in css.

```
<a href="#">Menu1</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="duck1" src="duck1.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="duck2" src="duck2.jpg"></a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img alt="duck3" src="duck3.jpg"></a></li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
ul > li { 
    display:none;
}

a:hover + ul > li {
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: I guess using all three would be the best, since having all the abilities to have a dropdown menu with picture buttons.